# Outcome from this experiment with solid hydrogen?

Tags: experimental-physics

Let's say that we have two solid hydrogen blocks (or at least two solid hydrogen lattices) in a vacuum. Both blocks have perfectly smooth surfaces which are later put together. Before putting blocks together both blocks are manipulated with magnetic field so that proton spins have the same arrangement within each block but different (opposite) between blocks.

[image]

In picture, each triangle presents a proton. Two triangles together presents hydrogen diatomic molecule and + and - signs presents spin up/down. Overall triangle pattern comes from the crystal structure of solid hydrogen.

After magnetic field manipulation we have the following setup (only touching lattices are presented).

[image]

What would happen when we put those blocks together with very slow, non-accelerating, motion? Let's assume also that we'll manage to put those blocks together so that protons contact head-to-head precisely spins transversely polarized.

Follow up question, would you be interested in conducting this experiment?

**Edit:** Paper related to this experiment -> [Antimatter Bomb](http://www.vixra.org/abs/1410.0146)

**Edit:** Let's say that instead of para-hydrogen we would use ortho-hydrogen. Playing around with ortho-hydrogen is a lot easier. But again, the idea is to put transverse anti-parallel spin protons together.

Comment: The question seems to contradict itself in that first it says "proton spins have the same arrangement within each block", but then shows all the hydrogen molecules as parahydrogen (spins arranged oppositely).  Also, they magnetic field would create and excess of spins oriented with the field.

Comment: @DavePhD I did mean that those spins are arranged as (arrangement 1) up-down-up-down-... and in the other block as (arrangement 2) down-up-down-up-...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hydrogen molecule where the proton spins form a spin singlet
$$
\left|s_1,s_2\right> = \frac{
\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right> - \left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>
}{\sqrt2}
$$
differs in energy from the spin triplet with
$$
\left|s_1,s_2\right> = \frac{
\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right> + \left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>
}{\sqrt2}
$$
by a whopping $15\,\rm meV$.  That's actually comparable to the heat of vaporization for the liquid.  It was discovered because room-temperature hydrogen is dominated by the orthohydrogen (triplet) state, which makes it hard to condense: you liquify the hydrogen, the extra density makes it much easier to convert to parahydrogen (spin singlet), and the liberated heat makes the liquid boil away again.

However, the rapid ortho-para down-conversion in liquid hydrogen happens because the molecular spins are mobile and it's easy for oppositely-oriented orthohydrogen molecules (remember that $\left|\uparrow\uparrow\right>$ is also orthohydrogen) to find each other and swap spins. For an isolated orthohydrogen molecule, the time for spontaneous conversion to parahydrogen is billions of years: it's the same dipole-dipole interaction as the one responsible for the [21-cm line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line), but feebler because the electron's magnetic moment is a thousand times larger than the proton's. You could create a solid hydrogen crystal with pure parahydrogen, or with some isolated orthohydrogen molecules, but solid orthohydrogen would be thermodynamically unstable for the same reason that liquid orthohydrogen is unstable.

The figures you have drawn, where you have specified $\left|s_1,s_2\right>=\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right>$ for every molecule on the lattice, are unphysical: that spin state is a superposition of para and ortho, and a macroscopic superposition of para and ortho would be like a macroscopic superposition of solid and liquid.

So let's suppose you have two orthohydrogen "defects" in a parahydrogen crystal, and you allow them to interact with each other. (This is the closest plausible interpretation I can think of to your proposal.)  What will happen is the spins will be allowed to interact, and the orthohydrogens will have an opportunity to convert to para — which will leave you without your orientable defects, and probably with a phonon energetic enough to free a molecule or two from the lattice.

Answer (score 1):

In solid hydrogen, the molecules freely rotate. See [Ultrahigh-pressure transitions in solid hydrogen](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.66.671) at page 672.

So at least because the molecules are constantly rotating, even in the solid, the alignment described in the question is not possible.

Also, how could one say that a particular atom of the molecule is spin up and the other down, as opposed to the wavefunction of the molecule being up-down minus down-up?